# Jest fails to import vue-test-utils with "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" exception

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js

I am using NuxtJS with Jest configured and Typescript. Now it happens that my little example test won't run because of an exception.

```
 Details:

    /home/xetra11/development/myapp/test/Navigation.spec.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
```

My unit test is rather simple

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Navigation from '@/components/layout/Navigation.vue'

describe('navigation', () => {
  test('is correct', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Navigation)
    expect(wrapper.vm).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

Here is my `jest.config.js` (I added `transformIgnorePatterns` because many googled solution suggested it)

```js
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^~/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'ts',
    'js',
    'vue',
    'json'
  ],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.ts$": "ts-jest",
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    '.*\\.(vue)$': 'vue-jest'
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js",
  ],
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/components/**/*.vue',
    '<rootDir>/pages/**/*.vue'
  ]
}
```

Here is also an excerpt from my `package.json`

```js
 "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.15.3",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.3",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.1.3",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.4",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.4"
  }
```

Any idea what the problem here is?

Comment: try updating node to the latest version

Comment: I am on node 16.1.0 - does not help

Comment: Can you link to a reproduction?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error that I fixed installing babel-core bridge:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-core@^7.0.0-bridge.0
```

I needed also the following one in jest.config.js:

```js
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
```

[Documentation](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/installation/#using-vue-test-utils-with-jest-recommended)